# How to get the URL of my WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I have created a very simple web service using Netbeans, Java EE6, JAX-WS and TomCat.
It just have one @WebMethod getWsdlURL(), which is supposed to return the URL of my wsdl, and it should be something similar to:

```
http://192.168.70.44:8088/SimpleWebService/WebService?wsdl
```

However I don't have any idea on how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are generating classes from a WSDL when you build, your service class will extend javax.xml.ws.Service and therefore will inherit the [`getWSDLDocumentLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#getWSDLDocumentLocation%28%29) method.

Comment: @VGR that comment is the only _answer_ to the actual question, why don't you put it in an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't add your own service to return the URL. Depend on the runtime, that already supplies it.

Just open the url in a browser.  The url would be....

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/<webappname>/<servletEndpoint>?wsdl
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to answer of david99world, you can look for the endpoint url-pattern in sun-jaxws.xml configuration file present in WEB-INF dir.

The file may have a definition like:

```xml
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">

    <endpoint name="ws/MyService" implementation="com.test.ws.services.MyService"
        url-pattern="/ws/MyService" enable-mtom="false" />

</endpoints>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating classes from a WSDL when you build, your service class will extend javax.xml.ws.Service and therefore will inherit the [`getWSDLDocumentLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#getWSDLDocumentLocation%28%29) method.