# Get WSDL from ServletContext

Tags: java, parsing, servlets, soap, wsdl

I'm running into a unique situation where I need a ServletFilter (during the init(FilterConfig) stage) to parse the WSDL of a SOAP Service deployed in the same WAR file.  My first though was to try and retrieve the WSDL using ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() but the problem is I won't know the where the wsdl is on the localfile system as its generated at runtime by the servlet container.  Typically, a webrequest could access the wsdl at:

```
    http://example.com/servicewarfile/service?wsdl
```

Any thoughts on how I could retrieve the input stream of the wsdl file?  The other thought was to use HttpURLConnections to access it but I won't know the port number of the local running servlet container at runtime (trying to remain implementation agnostic).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19181182/1138559

Comment: The problem with that is the servlet filter does not have an object reference to the web service class instance.  In order to use that method the service instance would have to be accessible by the filter

Comment: That's true. But can't you add the instance somewhere accessible by the filter?

Comment: Sadly no b/c this filter is not for 1 given soap service but will be used by multiple soap services without any expectations other then the servlet filter will be on the filter chain of the service endpoint